# Type-graphql with lerna --- Error: Cannot determine GraphQL output type for id

Tags: node.js, graphql, typeorm, lerna, typegraphql

I have recently moved from yarn/workspaces to lerna/npm, and in that move I have unearthed an unexpected problem.  I know get:

`Error: Cannot determine GraphQL output type for id` when generating my schema

I am using type-graphql along with typeorm (a wonderful combo)

My package structure looks like the following

```
/app
   /packages
       /utils (common functions)
       /data (my TypeORM entities, repos, factories, decorated with type-graphql)
       /server (my type-graphql server) deps on @app/data
       /server-test (tests my server) also deps on @app/data
```

after I do a:
lerna clean
cd app/packages/server
npm run start

I now get `Error: Cannot determine GraphQL output type for id`

both data and server's package.json refer to `"type-graphql": "^0.17.4"`

======
Note in: https://github.com/19majkel94/type-graphql/issues/69

@19majkel94 states the following:

> The last error Cannot determine GraphQL output type for id basically
>   comes from getGraphQLOutputType and convertTypeIfScalar which performs
>   if type instanceof GraphQLScalarType. The problem is that separate
>   project has separate node_modules so GraphQLScalarType !==
>   GraphQLScalarType.
>
> From my experience there's always too much problems from separating
>   things to projects/modules than the benefits of this. I would
>   recommend restructuring your app to don't need this.

So that seems a bit nuclear for me to forgo lerna, and modularization.  I would love to see if there is a way to make this work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use dependencies hoisting, so all your packages will use the `graphql` module from the root `node_modules`.